# HTML5, CSS3, PHP contact form not sending info + add required fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I've added a contact form to my website. The form sends out the email, however i'm not receiving the information. All the fields come out blank. Also, i'd like to make the fields required. Anyone?

Here's the PHP

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['Name...'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email...'];
$field_phone = $_POST['Phone...'];
$field_company = $_POST['Company'];
$field_message = $_POST['Message...'];

$mail_to = 'email@me.com';
$subject = '#Message from Website# '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Company: '.$field_company."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$E-Mail."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$E-Mail."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
  window.location = 'index.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Message sending failed. Please, send an email to         
email@me.com');
  window.location = 'index.html';
 </script>
<?php }
?>
```

Here's the Form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Name..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value =='') {this.value = 'Name...';}">
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Email..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email...';}">
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Phone..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone...';}">
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Company..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Company...';}">
    <textarea value="Message..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message...</textarea>
    <input class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.3s" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

Comment: This line have an extra `v`:
`v$field_phone = $_POST['Phone...'];`

Comment: That was a copy and paste mistake... my bad.

Comment: Now, how can i make the fields required?

Answer (score 1):

Its blank because your inputs do not have a name attribute.  All inputs need the name attribute.  Example:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
```

Comment: Now, how can i make the fields required?

Answer (score 1):

There are no name attributes in your HTML. Ensure that there are name attributes so that they are accessible in PHP.

Also, please be careful as to not name the attributes as "Name...", Remove the dots

Comment: I posted my answer first?  Why didn't I get an up vote?

Answer (score 0):

If your `$_POST` should return something for your attribution, you need to specify attribute `name` inside each input field you created with those respective value declared inside $_POST's.

Besides, you will probably face blank pages, which means you have a syntax error.

It was not difficult to find what is wrong.

At the line 4 of your snippet code, I can see there is a letter `v` among with your declared variable:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['Name...'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email...'];
v$field_phone = $_POST['Phone...'];
$field_company = $_POST['Company'];
$field_message = $_POST['Message...'];
```

Remove it and try to refresh the page again.
Also, It is important you to look at php_error_log and see what kind of error your are facing it.

**EDIT**

If you want to turn required field, HTML5 has a new attribute that you can include on each `input` tag called `required`.
Just add at the end of your `input` tag this attribute like this:

`<input type="text" class="text" name="Name" value="Name..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value =='') {this.value = 'Name...';}" required>`

There are a lot of new attributes for HTML5 you can find in here:  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

Comment: @RafaelGranato: As my answer is completed fetching another error that was off in your topic, I would ask you to accept my answer. I fixed two problems in your code. By the way, I edited my answer including on how to put required field in your fields. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` to check if the values are empty or not, eg:

```
if(!empty($field_name)) {
   // the field name is not empty and you can send the mail
   $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
}
```

Also you have to give your `<input />` fields the correct name. You could do this:

```
<?php $field_name = $_POST['fieldname']; ?>
<input name="fieldname" />
```

Comment: The if function to make the fields required didn't work... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're making a simple mistake - when an html input element posts to a php form, the index that it fills in the `$_POST` array is based on the `name` attribute of the html element, but you are using the `value` attribute instead.

I would also avoid strange characters like periods in your `name` attribute.

Try replacing

```
<input type="text" class="text" value="Name..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name...';}">
```

with

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name...';}">
```